# Deleting individual items from react-beautiful-dnd horizontal list

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-redux

I have react-beautiful-dnd horizontal multiple list(6 rows with the same items in each row) with the same items in each list.
I want to delete individual selected items from each list, but just having a button component with `onClick` fires the `onClick` while rendering the lists itself. How do i configure the list so that an individual item is deleted from that list when i click on the close/delete (x) button?

Below, is my code,

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { DragDropContext, Droppable, Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
    import {Button, Icon} from 'semantic-ui-react'

    // a little function to help us with reordering the result
    const reorder = (list, startIndex, endIndex) => {
    const result = Array.from(list);
    const [removed] = result.splice(startIndex, 1);
    result.splice(endIndex, 0, removed);
    return result;
    };

    const grid = 12;
    const getItemStyle = (isDragging, draggableStyle) => ({
    // some basic styles to make the items look a bit nicer
    userSelect: 'none',
    padding: grid / 2,
    margin: `0 ${grid}px 0 0`,

    // change background colour if dragging
    background: isDragging ? 'lightgreen' : 'lightgray',

    // styles we need to apply on draggables
    ...draggableStyle,
    });

    const getListStyle = isDraggingOver => ({
    background: isDraggingOver ? 'lightblue' : 'white',
    display: 'flex',
    padding: grid,
    overflow: 'auto',
    });

    class DragAndDrop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        items: this.props.uniqueEntries
        };
        this.onDragEnd = this.onDragEnd.bind(this)
        this.removeSubject = this.removeSubject.bind(this)
    }

    onDragEnd(result) {
        // dropped outside the list
        if (!result.destination) {
        return;
        }
        const items = reorder(
        this.state.items,
        result.source.index,
        result.destination.index
        );

        this.setState({
        items,
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
        this.setState({
        items : newProps.uniqueEntries
        })

    }

    removeItem = (index) => {
        this.state.items.splice(index, 1)
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.onDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="droppable" direction="horizontal">
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <div
                ref={provided.innerRef}
                style={getListStyle(snapshot.isDraggingOver)}
                {...provided.droppableProps}
                >
                {this.state.items.map((item, index) => (
                    <Draggable key={item.Id} draggableId={item.Id} 
                   index={index}>
                    {(provided, snapshot) => (
                        <div
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.draggableProps}
                        {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                        style={getItemStyle(
                            snapshot.isDragging,
                            provided.draggableProps.style
                        )}
                        >
                        <Button icon size='mini'
                        style={{backgroundColor : 'lightgray' ,padding: 
                        '0', float: 'right'}}
                        onClick = {this.removeItem(index)}>
                        <Icon name='close' />
                        </Button>
                        {item.name}
                        </div>
                    )}
                    </Draggable>
                ))}
                {provided.placeholder}
                </div>
            )}
            </Droppable>
        </DragDropContext>
        );
    }
   }

    export default DragAndDrop
```

Answer (score 2):

A Note for this bug that might hit you later and future viewers.

You are not supposed to mutate the state directly. It will have some side effects or none at all.

I also recommend you generate unique IDs because if you create more list, it will also have some unexpected result even `react-beautiful-dnd` won't notice.

If you want to update or remove state data, use `setState()`. First modify existing data with a **copy**. Then assign the new value.

```
removeItem(index) {

// do magic here to filter out the unwanted element

// Update via 'setState'
        this.setState({
            items : newModifiedItems
        })
}
```

For an example, my trial method below:

```
removeItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // give your single list a className so you can select them all
        const sourceList = document.querySelectorAll(".list-name");

        const arrList= Array.from(sourceList);

        // make shallow copy of your state data
        const newItems = Array.from(this.state.items);

        // Find index element from whole list Arr by traversing the DOM
        const removeItemIndex = arrList.indexOf(e.target.parentElement);

        // Remove it
        newItems.splice(removeItemIndex, 1);

        this.setState({
            items: newItems 
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out why it was firing at render, instead of passing the function i was initiating it so through the loop it was getting called. Then i did this and it worked. May be this will help someone who might face a similar issue.

```
<Button icon size='mini'
                  style={{backgroundColor : 'lightgray' ,padding: '0', 
  float: 'right', marginLeft:'15px'}}
                  onClick = {() => this.removeItem(index)}>
                  <Icon name='close' />
                </Button>
```