# Adding swipe to delete to drag and drop component

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a react web app that uses drag and drop (react-beautiful-dnd):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ef9gan

However, that package doesn't have a function to delete items in a list,so I want to use another package in order to swipe an input area off-screen to delete. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-swipe-to-delete-component

The problem I'm running into is that both of the packages use a .map function in order to render a list.

## React Swipe to Delete

```
const list = data.map(item => (
  <SwipeToDelete key={item.id} item={item}>
      //user code
  </SwipeToDelete>
)
```

## React Beautiful DnD (from stackblitz, simplified for post)

```
                      <div>
                        {this.state.inputs.map((input, index) => (
                          <Draggable key={input.id} draggableId={input.id} index={index}>
                            {(provided, snapshot) => (

                             // omitted code

                            )}
                          </Draggable>

                        ))}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                      </div>
```

I know I can render an icon by each field and delete the items like in this S/O question ([Deleting individual items from react-beautiful-dnd horizontal list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612683/deleting-individual-items-from-react-beautiful-dnd-horizontal-list)) but I'm trying to avoid using buttons for ascetic reasons.   I'm still new to React so this might be a n00b question, but is it possible to use the functions of two separate NPM packages in one view?